# Symfony and Doctrine - getDoctrine not found

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to build a simple app
I have a database with a table "matches"[the table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ri7M.png)

and i wrote this code as Entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="matches")
 */

class Match
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=512)
     */
    private $descr;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $team_a;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $team_b;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $location;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $datetime;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set descr
     *
     * @param string $descr
     *
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setDescr($descr)
    {
        $this->descr = $descr;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descr
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescr()
    {
        return $this->descr;
    }

    /**
     * Set teamA
     *
     * @param string $teamA
     *
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setTeamA($teamA)
    {
        $this->team_a = $teamA;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get teamA
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTeamA()
    {
        return $this->team_a;
    }

    /**
     * Set teamB
     *
     * @param string $teamB
     *
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setTeamB($teamB)
    {
        $this->team_b = $teamB;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get teamB
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTeamB()
    {
        return $this->team_b;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param string $location
     *
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    /**
     * Set datetime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $datetime
     *
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setDatetime($datetime)
    {
        $this->datetime = $datetime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get datetime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDatetime()
    {
        return $this->datetime;
    }
}
```

and this as controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use AppBundle\Entity\Match;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class AddMatch
{
    /**
     * @Route("/addmatch")
     */
    public function createAction()
    {
        $match = new Match();
        $match->setDescr('Descrizione Partita');
        $match->setTeamA('Squadra A');
        $match->setTeamB('Squadra B');
        $match->setLocation('a nice Gym');
        $match->setLocation('12/12/2012');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


        // tells Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Product (no queries yet)
        $em->persist($match);

        // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('Saved new match with id '.$match->getId());
    }

}
```

but it dosent work and I get [Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yeg8.png)

What am I missing?
I am super n00b :(
thanks for your help

Comment: You need to extend the base symfony controller in order to have the getDoctrine method available

Comment: you should extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` class

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Follow the example in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html There are several other things you need to do besides extending the symfony base controller class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to extend the base symfony controller:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AddMatch extends Controller
{
    ...
}
```

If, for some reason, you can't extend a controller, you still can use Doctrine entity manager. In that case you need to inject the service container and then get the entity manager with

```
$container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

You should thoroughly read [the Symfony guide on Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).